# I need to save the input value of the stars

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm just starting to code, and I was asked to create star reviews. I want to make a review where it is rated with stars from 1 to 5.

I am working with C# and ASP.NET MVC I have the controller where the punctuation is "saved" but it is not functional this part yet.

```
consola.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RESEÑA_COMIDA (ID_emp, Comentario, Puntuacion, Fecha) " +
                      "VALUES (NULL , @comentario, @puntuacion, GETDATE())";
consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("puntuacion", puntuacion);
consola.Parameters.AddWithValue("comentario", comentario);
```

I have the js where the stars should be saved, but I have not been able to convert the values so that they are saved. Only I have this in the js

```
$("#fmEmpleado").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    id_emp = $("#empleado").val();
    comentario = $("#comentario").val();
    puntuacion = $("#puntuacion").val();

    datos = new URLSearchParams();
    datos.append("id_emp", id_emp);
    datos.append("puntuacion", puntuacion);
    datos.append("comentario", comentario);

    fetch("Calificacion/GuardarComentario", { method: "POST", body: datos })
        .then(resultado => resultado.json())
        .then(function (resultado) {
            console.log(resultado)
            if (resultado.estatus) {
                datos = new URLSearchParams();
                datos.append("id_emp", id_emp);
                datos.append("puntuacion", puntuacion);
                datos.append("comentario", comentario);
```

I not sure it is necessary the cshtml but for whatever reason I will put it here

```
<form>
    <div id="puntuacion">
        <p class="clasificacion">
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="5">
            <label for="radio1">★</label>
            <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="4">
            <label for="radio2">★</label>
            <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="3">
            <label for="radio3">★</label>
            <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="2">
            <label for="radio4">★</label>
            <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="estrellas" value="1">
            <label for="radio5">★</label>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<button id="btnGuardar" class="d-block mx-auto my-3 btn btn-success" type="submit">Guardar</button>
```

I hope that the score can be selected when choosing a star, and this with its values from 1 to 5 can be saved in a table in SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
puntuacion = $("#puntuacion").val();
```

You're looking for the `value` of this element:

```
<div id="puntuacion">
```

A `div` doesn't *have* a value.  You want the value of the `input type="radio"` that's currently selected.  For example:

```
puntuacion = $('#puntuacion input[name="estrellas"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your button inside of the form tag.

Comment: I am not sure It's correct, but I have two forms, one with the name fmEmpleados and one with the stars. The button is inside fmEmpleados

Comment: Ok, so i didnt see. Just use following code to get value using pure javascript:

Comment: document.querySelector('input[name="estrellas"]:checked').value